# How do I make non-constant range an integer

Tags: swiftui

```
Picker("Size",selection: $size) {

    ForEach(sizeOption.indices) { index in
        Text(sizeOption[index])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the `id` parameter with the value `\.self`

```
Picker("Size",selection: $size) {
    ForEach(sizeOption.indices, id: \.self) { index in
        Text(sizeOption[index])
    }
}
```